# Wait after setVisibility() until widget is truely visible in the app

Tags: android, visibility, wait

In a function handling a registration form I want to set the visibility of button to invisible and the visibility of a progress bar to visible. The problem now is, that the following code which handles some OAuth requests seems to prevent the widgets to show their visibility exactly where I want them to.

Setting the visibility of the progressbar stops (is frozen?) until the oauth requests are finished. How can I fix that?! I think working with `sleep()`s, `wait()`s or timers would be a bad solution here...

```
private void registerOnce(){

    ProgressBar spinner = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);

    spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    login.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    // Here goes the code for some oauth requests
    // This code here seems to prevent setting the
    // the visibility where I want it to.

    spinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
```

Comment: if your registration method is maybe executed in another thread you should synchronize calls of `view.setVisibility()` method with the main application thread, but that's a guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
in `onPreExecute()`

```
 spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    login.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

in `doInBackground`

```
// Here goes the code for some oauth requests
    // This code here seems to prevent setting the
    // the visibility where I want it to.
```

And in `onPostExecute`

```
spinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Ok sounds like the best way to solve this problem. The Pre- and PostExecutes seem to completely match my problem. I will give it a try. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

separate your UI from heavy background process. your OATH requests is in the same thread with your UI. better run the heavy oerations (here oath connection) in another thread. or Try to use `AsyncTask`